# How to both post request and get response (nested JSON) with retrofit android

Tags: java, android, api, rest, retrofit

here are the nested JSON request

```
{
"user": {
    "email": "123@mail.com",
    "password": "12345678"
    }
}
```

here are the nested JSON response

```
{
    "data": {
        "renew_token": "e994c4d2-d93b-47e8-ab5f-9090b823f249",
        "token": "419fff70-b1ee-4ea7-b636-ddbec6346794"
    }
}
```

i am able to post the request but i'm struggling to code the response in the same process

my interface currently

```
public interface JsonApi {

    @POST("session")
    Call<RootUser> userLogin(@Body RootUser rootUser);
}
```

Model for request

```
public class User{
    public String email;
    public String password;
}

public class RootUser{
    public User user;
}
```

the API call

```
private void userLogin(){
        String email = etloginemail.getText().toString();
        String password = etloginpassword.getText().toString();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://the-digest-app.herokuapp.com/api/")
                                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                        .build();

        JsonApi jsonApi = retrofit.create(JsonApi.class);

        User user = new User(email, password);
        RootUser rootUser = new RootUser(user);

        Call<RootUser> call = jsonApi.userLogin(rootUser);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<RootUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RootUser> call, Response<RootUser> response) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RootUser> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

How to define the get response function? if i did something wrong, kindly tell me!

Comment: Your request and response are different! You will need to different POJOs like @mehmet said. How do we know it? Both the request and response contain two keys of type string but **both have different key names!**

Answer (score 1):

You should create one more POJO for response like

```
public class LoginResponse{
    @SerializedName("renew_token")
    public String renewToken;
    @SerializedName("token")
    public String token;
}

public class UserLoginResponse{
    public LoginResponse data;
}
```

and your retrofit interface should look like

```
public interface JsonApi {

    @POST("session")
    Call<UserLoginResponse> userLogin(@Body RootUser rootUser);
}
```

and your call implementation

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<UserLoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserLoginResponse> call, Response<UserLoginResponse> response) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserLoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have created the POJO and edit the interface, can you help me with calling the get response? im struggling because its in nested json format.

Comment: I edited my answer and add implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your help! sorry if my questions aren't clear enough but i am actually asking for the code for getting the response "token" and "renew_token" to store inside the class LoginResponse. If u can help that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Never mind i already figured it out. Wouldn't be possible without your help though :)